# PHP+MySQL add comma before select and LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, select

I select from `database` but i want add comma to value before select

> Table:

```
id      value
1       5,6
2       7,5,9,8
3       4,7,6
```

I want select value if LIKE ,6, return ID 1 and 3

> My code not work :

```
SELECT * FROM `,value,` LIKE ',6,'
```

Comment: What is the problem to use `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value LIKE '%6%';`?

Comment: Even `6` is not in the value list  you will get output for values like `66 or 16 or ...etc` @D.Dimitrioglo

Comment: '%,6%' OR '%6,%'?

Comment: what if `6` is the only element in the `value` column? @D.Dimitrioglo. One way you can make use of `like` in this case : `....CONCAT('%,',6,',%') LIKE CONCAT(',',`value`,',')....`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `find_in_set`

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(6,`value`);
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE CONCAT('%,',6,',%') LIKE CONCAT(',',`value`,',').
```

**Note on `FIND_IN_SET`:**

**FIND_IN_SET() function**

`MySQL FIND_IN_SET()` returns the position of a string if it is present (as a substring) within a list of strings. The string list itself is a string contains substrings separated by ‘,’ (comma) character.

This function returns 0 when search string does not exist in the string list and returns `NULL` if either of the arguments is `NULL`.

**Syntax :**

```
FIND_IN_SET (search string, string list)
```

**Arguments**

```
Name            Description
search string   A string which is to be looked for in following list of arguments.
string list     List of strings to be searched if they contain the search string.
```

**Caution:**

A must read:

[**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

<sub>Yes</sub>